# Sorting and removing duplicates of multi dimensional array flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hello I am working on a project here I have a multidimensional array with name and votes this is the array

```
[[[Avoos, 0]], [[Abhiram MS, 1]], [[Amritha tg, 0]], [[usha, 2]]]
```

I get this from the server,the problem is every time I refresh the page it stores these values again in the array(repeating the same values) so its getting something like this

```
[[[Avoos, 0]], [[Abhiram MS, 1]], [[Amritha tg, 0]], [[usha, 2]], [[Amritha tg, 0]], [[Abhiram MS, 1]], [[Avoos, 0]], [[usha, 2]], [[Amritha tg, 0]], [[Abhiram MS, 1]], [[Avoos, 0]], [[usha, 2]]]
```

I want to remove these repeated values and sort this array according to the votes

here is my complete code used on the page

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web3dart/web3dart.dart';

import '../../services/Auth.dart';
import '../../services/IntoLogin.dart';
import '../../services/functions.dart';

class CloseElec extends StatefulWidget {
  final Web3Client ethClient;
  final String electionName;
  final String electionAdress;
  const CloseElec({Key? key, required this.ethClient, required this.electionName, required this.electionAdress}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CloseElec> createState() => _CloseElecState();
}

class _CloseElecState extends State<CloseElec> {
  void refresh() {
    setState(() {
      //candidatearray.clear();
      candidatearray =candidatearrayreal.toSet().toList();
    });
  }
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    if (!mounted) return;
    await Auth().signOut();
    if (!mounted) return;
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => IntroLogin()),
            (route) => false);
  }

late String winner = 'No candidate';
late int winnervotes = 0;
late int row = 5;
late int col = 5;
var candidatearray = [] ;
  var candidatearrayreal = [] ;
@override
  void initState() {
    candidatearray.clear();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration:  const BoxDecoration(gradient:
      LinearGradient(colors: [
        Color(0xFF516395),
        Color(0xFF614385 ),
      ])),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar:AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          leading: IconButton(onPressed: () {
            signOut();
          }, icon: const Icon(Icons.logout_sharp),),
          title: const Text('Election progress'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(onPressed: () {
              refresh();
            }, icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh))
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(  //Here we are getting the whole candidate details
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 56),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(  // this stream builder will give the number of items/candidates
                  child: StreamBuilder<List>(stream: getCandidatesNum(widget.ethClient, widget.electionAdress).asStream(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);//circular bar for waiting
                      } else {
                        return Column(
                          children: [  // here we will get all candidates using a loop
                            for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data![0].toInt(); i++)
                              FutureBuilder<List>(  // call to get candidate info
                                  future: candidateInfo(i, widget.ethClient, widget.electionAdress),
                                  builder: (context, candidatesnapshot) {
                                    if (candidatesnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                                    } else {
                                      // logic to decide the winner
                                      if(candidatesnapshot.data![0][1].toInt() > winnervotes){
                                        winnervotes = candidatesnapshot.data![0][1].toInt();
                                        winner = candidatesnapshot.data![0][0];
                                      }else if(candidatesnapshot.data![0][1].toInt() == winnervotes){
                                        winner = candidatesnapshot.data![0][0];
                                      }
                                      candidatearrayreal.add(candidatesnapshot.data);
                                     // print(candidatesnapshot.data);
                                      return Container(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(color: Color(0xFF7F5A83),
                                                offset: Offset(-11.9, -11.9),
                                                blurRadius: 39,
                                                spreadRadius: 0.0,
                                              ),
                                              BoxShadow(color: Color(0xFF7F5A83),
                                                offset: Offset(11.9, 11.9),
                                                blurRadius: 39,
                                                spreadRadius: 0.0,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                              Color(0xFF74F2CE),
                                              Color(0xFF7CFFCB),
                                            ])),
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text('Name: ${candidatesnapshot.data![0][0]}',
                                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
                                          subtitle: Text('Votes: ${candidatesnapshot.data![0][1]}',
                                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }
                                  })
                          ],
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 12,),
              Text('The winner of the election is : $winner with votes $winnervotes',style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              const SizedBox(height: 16,),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount:candidatearray.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      for (var i = 0; i < candidatearray.length; i++) {
                        candidatearray.sort((a, b) {
                          print(candidatearrayreal);
                          //print(b[0][1]);
                          return int.parse(a[0][1].toString()).compareTo(int.parse(b[0][1].toString()));
                        });
                      }
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('${candidatearray[index][0][0]}'),
                        subtitle:Text('votes : ${candidatearray[index][0][1]}'),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show output of array which you want ?

Comment: Why are you doing `candidatearrayreal.add(candidatesnapshot.data)` rather than just replacing the existing list? It would seem that is the source of undesired duplication.

Comment: @ChuckBatson how can I do that ?? is it ok to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a lot like a task a **model class** would make **100** times easier. Instead of using a multi-dimensional array where you might make various different mistakes, you can combine the data into a single object and get IDE support too.

In your case, that class could look like this:

```
class MyObject {
  final String name;
  final int votes;

  MyObject({required this.name, required this.votes});

}
```

When you receive the data in your `FutureBuilder` you will need to transform the list of lists into a list of these objects. This is already much better, but there's more!

You can implement the `=`= and `hashCode` overrides which allows you to compare two of the same objects and determine whether they are equal or not. Write this in your model class too:

```
@override
bool operator ==(covariant MyObject other) {
  if (identical(this, other)) return true;
  return 
    other.name == name &&
    other.votes == votes &;
}

@override
int get hashCode {
  return name.hashCode ^
    votes.hashCode;
}
```

Now you can compare them anywhere by simply writing `==`:

```
MyObject a = MyObject(name: "test", votes: 10);
MyObject b = MyObject(name: "test", votes: 10);
MyObject c = MyObject(name: "xyz", votes: 0);
print(a == b); // true
print(a == c); // false
```

What this also allows you to do is instead of storing the returned list `candidatesnapshot.data`, you can create a `Set`, which only allows any given value to be stored inside it a single time! This automatically eliminates you from adding duplicates, if that isn't what you want.

To do this, you're going to have to fix up the code after your `FutureBuilder`. I'm not going to lie, I don't really understand what's going on there since you seem to be creating a new `FutureBuilder` for every object returned by the `Stream`. Either way, I think it would be best to simply loop over the values from the stream and add the data to the `Set`.

Now, you can also easily sort this set of your `MyObjects`. Simply get the values as a list and then use the lists `.sort` method.

```
Set<MyObjects> m = {...}; // your data goes here
final sortedList = m.toList()..sort((a, b) => a.votes.compareTo(b.votes));
```

Since the types are only `int` and `string`, you can use their `compareTo` methods and automatically sort them. To reverse the order, simply reverse `a` and `b` on the sort function!

If you for some reason can't use a model class - and I *really* don't see why you couldn't - it is still possible to filter out duplicates by either:

- overwriting the list every time you get new data (using `x = ..` instead of `x.add()`
- checking for duplicates by looping over the list for every new value / using the `.contains()` method on the list

As for sorting, you can use the `.sort()` method, you'll just have to use a `[index]` syntax instead of object fields on the right side, which really isn't great either.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the repeated values and sort the array according to the votes, you can use the `toSet()` function and then convert it back to a list using `toList()`. This will remove any duplicate values. Then you can use the `sort()` function to sort the array according to the votes.

```
candidatearray = candidatearrayreal.toSet().toList();
candidatearray.sort((a, b) => a[1].compareTo(b[1]));
```

This will first convert the `candidatearrayreal` to a set, which will remove any duplicate values, and then convert it back to a list. Next, it will sort the list according to the second element of each sublist (which is the number of votes) using the `sort()` function and a comparator function that compares the votes of the two candidates.

You can put this piece of code in the `refresh()` function, so it will be executed every time the user refreshes the page.

Also, you can move the `candidatearray.clear();` code to the `initState()` function, this will clear the array every time the user enters the CloseElec page.

Comment: i tried this but still its the same ,issue is not solved